# Есть ли какой нибудь event listener на фокус окна?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

На пример я открыл ссылку сайта через ctrl или колёсиком мыши. Через минуту я зашёл на сайт и должен заиграть звук. Есть ли для этого event listener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть. Вы удивитесь, но он называется "focus".

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
  // дудочка, играй!
  console.log("ду-ду-ду");
});
```

Его противоположность:

```
window.addEventListener("blur", function(event) { ... });
```

Comment: Всё заработало. Есть такой вопрос: почему не работает `window.onfocus = function() { }` ?

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev есть пример, где это не работает?

Comment: @Дмытрык уже нашёл ошибку. Не работает запись вида `window.onfocus = greetings.play;`, а запись вида `window.onfocus = function () { greeting.play(); };` - работает. [Здесь](http://playcaz.xyz). (Источники - IndexScripts - 18 строка - вызывает ошибку, если сменить активное окно, а потом вернуться.)

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Illegal invocation` - ошибка

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотели Игорю написать?

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev для вызова метода `play` важен контекст, поэтому вариант с анонимной функцией-оберткой - правильный.

Comment: @Дмытрык я видел вчера ссылку на Ваш вопрос, но не успел вникнуть

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev Возможно, `window.onfocus = greetings.play.bind(greetings);` тоже будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо) Grundy посоветовал составить другой вопрос. Я тот пока удалил)